# What's the best approach in migrating currently C# and VB.net (Windows) developed applications?

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development, programming, ide, c#

I would like to start to "translate" my Windows applications to Ubuntu users. These are mainly CRMs or CRM related programs written in VB.net and C#.

What would be the best language and IDE for these kind of projects in Ubuntu? This is the first time in my life when Googling confused me instead of helping with the decision.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you considered Mono? This must have been one of the first hits in Google about C# development in Ubuntu. It should not be too hard to migrate your code to be Mono-compatible. @ close-for-offtopic-voter(s): this is a valid development question in my opinion. Also see [How should we interpret “Development on Ubuntu” in the FAQ?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5744/how-should-we-interpret-development-on-ubuntu-in-the-faq)

Comment: You'll probably be better off asking this on Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/), a dedicated software development Q&A site similar to AskUbuntu.

Comment: Note for the Close voters: I don't think, this is an off-topic question on the site. Since developing on Ubuntu and related IDE suggestions are accepted.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question?

It is quite valid: Gilad has already made applications on Windows, and is after assistance on how to reproduce them or repackage them in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Since your application uses .NET framework, You could use MONO project, which is open-source implementation of Dot net framework. A good IDE for mono is monodevelop. You can install it from Software center.

or using the terminal: `sudo apt-get install monodevelop`

Comment: Thanks.... Is it .net framework with the same class libraries like in win?

Comment: Yes. at least most of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can now try visual studio code. Microsoft's [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) with support for Mac, Linux and Windows.